# calling std:make_shared via a std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have build a factory pattern using new C++11 features. To achieve this a std::function is registered in the registry. Now I am trying to implement the instantiation part. Right now it is implemented like this:

```
std::map<uint32_t, std::function<Class*()>>::iterator it = m_creators.find(id);
if(it != m_creators.end())
{
    return std::shared_ptr<Class>((it->second)());
}
```

The problem is, that is is obviously not exception save and I am trying to replace the std::shared_ptr call with a equivalent std::make_shared call. The std::function is a create function that only calls the constructor of a Object subclass. The problem is that I have no idea how to use the std::function instead of the call to the constructor in std::make shared. Is this even possible?

Comment: *Why* do you want to use `make_shared` when the solution you have should work fine? If you see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) `std::make_shared` is no more exception safe.

Comment: Why isn't it exception-safe?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, to be fair "*why*", is exactly why he is asking the question and could probably do with your experience :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it is not exception-safe, because a Class instance could be created, while the shared_ptr throws an exception. In this case delete will not be called, which leads to memory leaks. Using make_shared this is not the case.

Comment: @evotion That is not correct; if `shared_ptr` throws an exception during construction it'll `delete` the pointer passed to it. The relevant standard quote is in my answer below.

Comment: @Praetorian OK yes I was wrong. The memory leak is just occuring in the case of the following call and if `g` is throwing a exception:
`f(shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), g())`

For more information see [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the std::function return a shared_ptr rather than a naked pointer. Then you could use make_shared inside the std::function.

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, std::function<std::shared_ptr<Class>()>> CreatorMap;
CreatorMap::iterator it = m_creators.find(id);
if(it != m_creators.end())
{
    return (it->second)();
}

// example of a creator

struct SomeCreator{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Class> operator()(){
        return std::make_shared<Class>();
    }
}
```

this also allows more flexibility to allow the factory to use custom deleter.

Comment: Thanks, why didn't I came up with that. It's just plain simple.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is not exception unsafe. The `shared_ptr` constructor that takes a pointer will call `delete` on the managed pointer if an exception occurs during initialization.

From N3797, *§20.8.2.2.1/7*

> `template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y* p);`
>   
> ...
>   *Exception safety:* If an exception is thrown, `delete p` is called.

If it makes you feel better, you could change the `map` type to

```
std::map<uint32_t, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Class>()>>
```

`shared_ptr`s can be constructed from `unique_ptr`s, and you're never passing around a raw pointer in this case. But it is unnecessary because of the clause I quoted above.

Comment: the class is newed inside the overloaded function call operator of the factory std::function, what if something is thrown between the new and the return? not likely but possible.

Comment: @PorkyBrain Well that would be an error in how the factory function is written. Anyway, my edit addresses that issue.

Comment: although not asked by the OP this would still not allow the factory to add a custom deleter to the shared pointer for no trivially destructible types or custom allocators that need a custom deleter.

Comment: @PorkyBrain Yes, assuming each of his polymorphic types requires a deleter with a different signature, which would be uncommon, to say the least. Having a factory return a `shared_ptr` means the caller cannot `release()` the managed pointer, which is why I prefer the `unique_ptr` approach.